# Should I use @Transactional using @EnableTransactionManagement?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I've got a Spring Boot application. Everything works fine. I'm just trying to understand how does transaction manager work, because I have suspicion about my application. In particular, I'm a little confused about annotations.

Here is `Application.java` (main class):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

config class `DataConfig.java` looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.pr.hotel")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pr.hotel")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DataConfig
{
    // code
}
```

I'm worry about `@EnableTransactionManagement`. What exactly does this annotation mean? Should I use `@Transactional` in this case (I don't)?

Comment: Remove your `DataConfig`. Spring Boot does already do all that for you. Make sure your `Application` class is in the `com.pr.hotel` (as advised by the Spring Boot Team).

Comment: @M.Deinum even without @EnableAutoConfiguration?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, but the main question is about `@EnableTransactionManagement`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@EnableTransactionManagement` does exactly what it says:

> Enables Spring's annotation-driven transaction management capability,
>   similar to the support found in Spring's  XML namespace.

Yes, you should still use `@Transactional` annotation on methods that you want to wrap in a transaction. In the following example the result of `saveSomething()` wouldn't be applied if `maybethrowaneException()` threw an exception. Be careful to use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and not `javax.transaction.Transactional`.

The `@Transactional` annotation tells Spring to control when the data are flushed to the database (typically once the method successfully completes). Without the annotation the data would be flushed immediately.

It's a mechanism to prevent incomplete changes being written to the database when something goes wrong. Further reading: https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional

```
@Service
public class DataTransformer() {

     @Transactional
     public void doETL() throws Exception {
        loadSomeEntities();
        saveSomething();
        maybethrowanException();
        saveSomethingElse();
     }
 }
```

Comment: could you explain what happens if I don't use `@Transactional`? because I don't and everything works good.

Comment: flushing isn't committing, flushing data in a transaction doesn't matter. With `@Transactional` the whole method is in a single transaction and you can rollback if something goes wrong. Without it, you have 4 different tx and aren't able to rollback the previous changes.

Comment: @M.Deinum i thought spring will reuse a transaction if there are any in this one particular service thread. isn't that the case?